# Using Patchage, can I connect Musescore to a soft synthesizer

Tags: music, midi, audio-jack

I'm missing a few connections here. I'm learning how to route things around in Ubuntu 15 with Patchage. I see from the UI that [MuseScore](https://musescore.org/) appears to have a Jack MIDI in and out.

[image]

I have the following jack related packages installed.

```
$ dpkg --list | grep jack | awk '{print $2}'
jack-keyboard
jackd
jackd2
jackd2-firewire
libjack-jackd2-0:i386
qjackctl
```

My question: Is there a Jack midi soft synth that I could wire up in patchage? Am I approaching this incorrectly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I ended up installing Yoshimi and ended up using JACK MIDI in MuseScore's preferences.

[image]
[image]